# Deal and Discard buttons not showing

Tags: swift, swiftui

There should be a deal and a discard button which deals a card to the player and then the player can discard the card

Just expecting that the buttons show up. The buttons are in a tool bar but I am not sure if that is the best way to do it. I just want the buttons to be at the center of the screen. Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct Card: Hashable {
    let rank: String
    let suit: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
    let suits = ["clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"]
    let cardWidth: CGFloat = 100
    let cardHeight: CGFloat = 150
    
    @State private var playerHand: [Card] = []
    @State private var deck: [Card] = []
    @State private var discardPile: [Card] = []
    @State private var deckImages: [String] = []
    
    private func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        var deck = [Card]()
        for suit in suits {
            for rank in ranks {
                deck.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
            }
        }
        return deck
    }
    
    private func deal() {
        guard let card = deck.first else { return }
        playerHand.append(card)
        deck.removeFirst()
        deckImages.removeFirst()
    }
    
    private func discard() {
        guard let card = playerHand.first else { return }
        discardPile.append(card)
        playerHand.removeFirst()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(playerHand, id: \.self) { card in
                    Image(card.rank + "_of_" + card.suit)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Image(deckImages.first ?? "card_back")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
                    
                    Text("Cards left: \(deck.count)")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    ForEach(discardPile, id: \.self) { card in
                        Image(card.rank + "_of_" + card.suit)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
                    }
                    
                    Text("Cards discarded: \(discardPile.count)")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            deck = createDeck().shuffled()
            deckImages = deck.map { $0.rank + "_of_" + $0.suit }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button("Deal") {
                    deal()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button("Discard") {
                    discard()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `NavigationView` or a `NavigationStack` wrapping this `ContentView`? On iOS, toolbars only appear inside navigation views.

Comment: Your code works well for me, on MacOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
Maybe it is different on older systems. The buttons show up in the`toolbar` at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your buttons are not showing up because the toolbar that contains these buttons is placed in the **'.bottomBar'** placement, which is not visible on devices that do not have a physical home button. To fix this, you can change the placement of the toolbar to **'.navigationBarTrailing'** or **'.navigationBarLeading'**.